# Android/Linux File Permissions Problem

Tags: android, linux, permissions, adb

I have created a directory in my app's internal storage (/data/data/com.my_app) and gave global read/write permissions to the directory via the method

`context.getDir(DATA_DIR_NAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE | Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);`

Through my app, I verified that the linux file permissions are correct:

`drw-rw-rw- app_71   app_71            2010-11-16 18:38 app_data`

And I was able to read/write files in-to/out-of the directory app_data just fine.  However, one of my developers suddenly wasn't able to write to the directory anymore.  Our application has trouble accessing the directory on his device as well.

The strange thing is that the file permission for the directory is still the same.  We can't do any sort of writes to the directory, and we can't read any files within the directory anymore either (the files were given global rw permission previously).

The only thing we can do is `adb shell ls /data/data/my_app/app_data` to see our list of files.  Doing `adb shell ls -l /data/data/my_app/app_data` strangely doesn't return anything.  And we can't CD into the directory either.

Does anyone have any pointer on what the problem is or how to solve this?  We are at our wit's end.

Much appreciated.

Comment: is there ANYTHING useful in the logs while you try to access the dir from the phone that doesn't open it ?

Comment: ADB Shell commands doesn't return anything useful.  If I try to read/write a file in the directory through my application, it throws an exception that describes Permission Denied.  With drw-rw-rw- permissions for the directory, I would expect to be able to at least write a file.  And nothing related besides the exception stacktrace is printed in logcat.

Answer (score 1):

Directories need to have the execute (X) bit set to be able to access the contents of the directory. I don't know the android modes, but look for `MODE_WORLD_EXECUTABLE` and see if you can set that.

Basically, you need mode 0777 (rwxrwxrwx) for a directory to be globally accessed with all permissions.

The reason `ls` works is that you have permission to read the filenames in the directory. `ls -l` does not work, because you cannot access the files in the directory to get the metadata that `-l` will print.